# joining two tables with a third table

Tags: mysql

I wasn't sure what to put into the title for this...please read on...

I have a table of events with 3 days per event

```
eventID dayID
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       1
2       2
2       3
```

I also have a number of cars available for the event

```
carID regNum
1     fg12 bfr
2     gh34 vbn
3     kl56 thg
4     lm32 tfx
```

I would like to have certain cars available for certain events, for example carIDs 1,2 and 3 might be available for eventID 1 but only carID 4 is available for event 2.

I am unsure how to join these tables together.

I am looking at another table which defines which cars are available to which event for example

```
eventID carID
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       4
```

but I can't work out how to join these 3 tables together to get the car list for event1 for example.

Any pointers gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Junction tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) are the classic solution for modeling a many-to-many relationship in an RDBMS.

You do not need to join three tables to get cars for event1 - two tables is enough:

```
select *
from Cars c
join CarEvent e on e.CarId = c.CarId
where e.EventId = 1
```

If you need the event name, you need to join the event table as well:

```
select *
from Cars c
join CarEvent ce on ce.CarId = c.CarId
join Event e on e.EventId = ce.EventId
where e.EventName = 'Event1'
```

Comment: I need to add in the event table because it also contains an Event name that I need to include, so I think I need to add in the event table as well.

Comment: Adding in the event name gives me too many records, since there are 3 days per event so the joing gives me 3x the amount of records I need

Comment: @Dave Then it's not an `Event` but an `EventDay` table, and `EventName` does not belong there (it's replicated for each day). You should refactor it into three tables - `Event` with `EventId`, `EventName`, etc.; one record per event; `Day` table with `DayId` and other day attributes, and `EventDay`, a junction table similar to your `CarEvent` table.

Comment: ok, I undersdtand the need for an extra table and will factor this in. Many thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT e.id, c.carID, c.regNum
FROM tblEvents e
JOIN tblEventCars ec ON ec.eventID = e.eventID
JOIN tblCars c ON c.carID = ec.carID
GROUP BY e.id, c.carID
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I get3 times the amount of records that I need because there are 3 records per event in the event table